# VSCode issue running old container

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I am trying to run a dev container with an old version of node (8.x). When trying to launch I get this error:

```
Start: Run in container: /root/.vscode-server/bin/660393deaaa6d1996740ff4880f1bad43768c814/bin/code-server --log debug --force-disable-user-env --server-data-dir /root/.vscode-server --telemetry-level off --accept-server-license-terms --host 127.0.0.1 --port 0 --connection-token-file /root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.connection-token-660393deaaa6d1996740ff4880f1bad43768c814 --extensions-download-dir /root/.vscode-server/extensionsCache --start-server 
[2647 ms] Command failed: /root/.vscode-server/bin/660393deaaa6d1996740ff4880f1bad43768c814/bin/code-server --log debug --force-disable-user-env --server-data-dir /root/.vscode-server --telemetry-level off --accept-server-license-terms --host 127.0.0.1 --port 0 --connection-token-file /root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.connection-token-660393deaaa6d1996740ff4880f1bad43768c814 --extensions-download-dir /root/.vscode-server/extensionsCache --start-server 
[2647 ms] /vscode/vscode-server/bin/linux-x64/660393deaaa6d1996740ff4880f1bad43768c814/node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by /vscode/vscode-server/bin/linux-x64/660393deaaa6d1996740ff4880f1bad43768c814/node)
/vscode/vscode-server/bin/linux-x64/660393deaaa6d1996740ff4880f1bad43768c814/node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /vscode/vscode-server/bin/linux-x64/660393deaaa6d1996740ff4880f1bad43768c814/node)
/vscode/vscode-server/bin/linux-x64/660393deaaa6d1996740ff4880f1bad43768c814/node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /vscode/vscode-server/bin/linux-x64/660393deaaa6d1996740ff4880f1bad43768c814/node)
/vscode/vscode-server/bin/linux-x64/660393deaaa6d1996740ff4880f1bad43768c814/node: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by /vscode/vscode-server/bin/linux-x64/660393deaaa6d1996740ff4880f1bad43768c814/node)
```

I think this has to do with VSCode trying to SSH and expecting more modern libs?

So how do I run an old container? The entire point of my attempt is to load an old project that I cannot run locally due to modern Python and other things. So I am attempting to recreate an older env including all the libs such as glibc etc.

Comment: do you have code version  1.69.0 or + ?

Comment: see this https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6936

Comment: @jmvcollaborator 1.80.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error what i can infer is that you might need to install some prerequisites for your linux distro.

From VSCode [official site](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh):

> glibc based Linux distributions for x86_64, ARMv7l (AArch32), and ARMv8l (AArch64)
> should work if they have the needed prerequisites.

Refer to prerequisites [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/linux).

Then you can keep moving forward with the installation/fix as described on the link above.

If needed refer to [VS Code Server](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/vscode-server) (it is on your error messages).

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks for link.Sadly looks like using containers will not help me when in vscode since they require fairly modern libs. Will just use Docker directly.

Answer (score 1):

Hey it looks like you need to install `Glibc` for vscode to run node 8.x

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1712

Here is a solved Github issue on how someone with a similar problem fixed it, and they added steps on how to `manually` install the needed dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. From links in other answer it appears VSCode wont be able to work with this. It looks like the issue goes beyond glibc and will affect Python and others. I had high hopes for this :(